# Run UNION SELECT only if the fist select is not empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure that returns rows for an endless scroll page. How can I check that newTable is empty? If it's empty then I don't want the UNION SELECT to be executed. Note that newTable is a very complex query so I don't want to execute more than once.

```
@offset INT,
@fetch INT
WITH newTable AS
(
SELECT * FROM table1
ORDER BY id OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @fetch ROWS ONLY
)
```

> Don't run the following if newTable has reached the last row and is empty

```
SELECT * FROM newTable
UNION
SELECT * FROM table3
UNION
SELECT * FROM table4
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do something like this:

```
DECLARE @offset INT, 
        @fetch INT;

WITH newTable AS
(
SELECT * FROM table1
ORDER BY id OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @fetch ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT * 
FROM newTable
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM table3
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM newTable)
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM table4
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM newTable)
ORDER BY id
```

I'm pretty sure it will not execute the cte again. If it does, you can use a temporary table instead of a cte:

```
SELECT <ColumnsList> INTO #TemporaryTable
FROM....
```

and then your UNION query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM #TemporaryTable
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM table3
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TemporaryTable)
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM table4
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TemporaryTable)
ORDER BY id
```